# Which lover of a Russian Empress obtained the highest rank?

Tags: russia, government, sex

There were numerous well-known [male lovers of Russian Empresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Male_lovers_of_Russian_royalty), particularly those of [Catherine the Great](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catherine_the_Great). Such a role often meant receiving sumptuous gifts such as beautiful apartments, the status of minor nobility, and grants of serfs.

Some of these men got appointments in the government bureaucracy as well. Which of them was placed highest in the Petrine [Table of Ranks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Ranks)?

Comment: Rasputin immediately comes to mind

Comment: @Bregalad:Rasputin's "relationship" with Alexandra was disputed, to say the least. And I think "Empresses" meant "reigning" Empresses, such as Anna, Elizabeth, and Catherine

Comment: I have to say, limiting this question to the Table of Ranks is akin to asking what's the biggest fish, but coming back and saying you don't consider sharks as fish.

Comment: @Spencer why? are there ranks in government service that don't appear in the Table? the whole point of it seems to be its universality.

Comment: @AaronBrick The table is limited to the Russian court, and the Empress's influence wasn't.

Comment: @Spencer the court ranks are only one column and only above rank VIII. please go ahead and ask the broader question that you like better, as I'm still not sure what it would be.

Comment: @AaronBrick You've already asked the "broader question", in the title. No more arguing, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to aforementioned Count Potemkin, Count [Alexei Razumovsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexei_Razumovsky) was a lover (or even a morganatic spouse) of the Empress Elizaveta and also a Field Marshal (1756).

In fact, Razumovsky is no lesser known than Potemkin.

Answer (score 5):

[Count Potemkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigory_Potemkin), lover of Catherine the Great. was a Field Marshal, Privy Counsellor (both literally and figuratively) and therefore member of the highest rank on your table of ranks. He is probably the best-known of imperial lovers.

Comment: Good stuff. As you stated, noone outranked a Field Marshal, so Potemkin is either the sole answer or one of several answers.

Comment: The next in line would be [Naryshkin (Russian wiki)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%91%D0%BD_%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), who was a Oberjägermeister - rank II. Third - [Biron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Johann_von_Biron) - grand chamberlain, rank III.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov thank you for the context! i expected Platon Zubov to be in there; do you happen to know his rank too?

Comment: @AaronBrick He was a General-Feldzeugmeister, which makes him rank II and actually higher than Biron. I guess I somehow missed him. Another high-ranked favourite of Ekaterine was [Zorich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semyon_Zorich) (lieutenant-general, rank III), but he seems to have earned his rank *after* he fell out of favour, so I guess he was actually a competent commander.

Comment: cheers, Danila. what a rich bunch of stories.

Answer (score 5):

To think outside the Matryoshka dolls for a second, [Stanisław August Poniatowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanis%C5%82aw_August_Poniatowski) was allegedly a lover of Catherine between 1755-1758 (and the father of her daugher Anna), and was placed on the throne of Poland in 1764. Although the Sejm voted him in, Russia was essentially in control of Poland at the time and they voted Catherine's candidate in. (They'd had to do it before [in 1736](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_the_Polish_Succession) for Augustus III under Empress Anna).

So although Poniatowski had to do Catherine's bidding, such as standing by while his country was dismembered, as King of Poland and Grand Duke of Lithuania, he nominally outranked any of his Russian counterparts.

Comment: I will add sources if I find some meaningful non-Wikipedia ones.

Comment: I don't doubt your facts, but the question was 'which lover obtained the highest rank," not which lover had the highest rank "going in."

Comment: @TomAu I'm not sure what you mean. Poniatowski "went in" as a 23 year old son of a Polish politician and only became king because of his association with Catherine.  So, he still wins.

Comment: What was Poniatowski's rank in Russia?

Comment: @AaronBrick None. At that point Poland was not a part of Russian Empire (at least officially) - the partition would only come in 1795, so while Poniatowski held a title in Poland, he was outside of russian Table of Ranks. And he never held any office in Russia.